# How to turn a repeating list into a Dataframe?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop

I've created a list of 35 rainfall values which I'm trying to turn into a data frame. The list counts 0-6, then repeats 5 times. I want to turn it into such a form that the 0-6 will form one row of the dataset, then will repeat and the next time it counts 0-6 it will create a new row. Here's a photo of what I mean:

[image]

Heres what the list currently looks like (the list is called meanlist):

[image]

What I'm looking to do is to keep these exact values, but show them in a table format, where the first 7 values make up the first row, the second 7 values make up the second row, etc.

I have tried creating a double-stacked for loop that runs through the data and appends to a database:

```
counter = 0
datatable=[[2,5,10,25,50,100,1000]]
for i in range(5):
    templist = []
    for x in range(7):
        templist.append(meanlist[counter][1])
        counter = (counter + 1)
    datatable.append(templist)
```

This, however doesn't work the way I hoped it would, and doesn't append the values into rows. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong in this loop?

Comment: What is `meanlist`? Can you share what your desired result would look like? I'm having a hard time following.

Comment: Apologies if it's unclear, I've edited the post to add some clarity. meanlist is the name of the list of values. My desired outcome is to show this exact list of values, but change its format to a dataframe/table. It will be a 7 column table with 5 rows, so I want the first 7 values of the list to make up the first row of the table, and so on.